# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, include, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a file that includes another file:

index.php is a dynamic template

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    include(functions.php);
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    $preparedStatement = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1");
    $preparedStatement->execute();
    $firstId = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
?>
```

when functions.php executes I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

at line

```
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1");
```

What is wrong with this code such that it throws the error?

Edit: The error arose from me connecting directly the the functions.php file, it did not appear when it was included from index.php, the problem I had was content not loading in later inclusions, that was caused by me forgetting to properly address arrays in a later included file. The selected answer is correct for the question I presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inclusion of files is wrong;

include `index.php` on `function.php` page   only , dont include vice versa

best practice to use `include_once`

Comment: If I do that I have the files including each other, and they just keep loading.

Comment: I need index.php to load functions.php, index.php is a dynamic template.