# how can i resolve this error ? [function.mysql-real-escape-string]

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code :

```
<?php
    // Get values from form
    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "No information has entered";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Return to Homepage</a>";
        exit;
    }

    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="pin"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="test"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // Insert data into mysql
            $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET `Used` = '1' WHERE `test`.`Code` =$name;";
            //echo $sql; exit;
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
            if($result){
                echo "Your Information </br>";
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<a href='index.html'></a>";
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT Code FROM `test` WHERE  `Code` =$name" );
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            printf("Code: %s </br>", $row[0]); 
                                $foundcode=$row[0];
                    }
                    if (!empty($foundcode)) {
                        echo "<BR>";
                        echo "<a href='".$foundcode.".pdf'>Click here to download.</a>";
                    }
                        if (empty($foundcode)){
                        echo "<BR>";
                        echo "Password is wrong";
                        }
                        mysql_free_result($result);
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<a href='index.php'>Exit</a>";
            }

            else {
                echo nl2br ("Entered Information are not valid, Please enter valid information </br></br>");
                echo "<a href='index.php'>Return to Homepage</a></br></br>";
            }

        // close connection
        mysql_close();
?>
```

but i receive this error:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I read some help but i can't fix it .
I read some answer about this problem like:

1. [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689349/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-in)
   [PHP Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607997/php-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-error)
   [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837403/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-with-pdo)

Although i change the DB user & pass but that problem still is Exist.

Comment: the real in the command means the escaping is done by the connection to the mysql server, so you cant escape befor you have connected... move the connect line befor the escaping and it will work.

Comment: oh and btw.. the mysql_ functions are deprecated.. use mysqli_

Comment: PDO is another option to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` needs a database connection, because the way that escaping should be done depends on connection parameters.

The MySQL extension of PHP tries to create a database connection if it needs one and does not find one that can be used. Hence the error message.

Call `mysql_real_escape_string()` after `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: how can i create mysql connection?

Comment: @KhosroYazdan http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php (and read the warning please)

Comment: Although this answer is literally correct, it is missing the question context by a mile.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The question is "how can i resolve this error ?". How does "Call `mysql_real_escape_string()` after `mysql_connect()`" miss the question context?

Comment: @KhosroYazdan - you are already creating the mysql-connection but AFTER the call to mysql_real_escape_string(). Therefore: Move code-block with mysql_real_escape_string() below the mysql_connect and mysql_select_db - calls.